# Apache tomcat9 SSL redirect broken, SSL not working

Tags: ssl, tomcat, https, keystore

I have a legacy application that I have no idea what's inside. The app is running on a windows 10 server under `http` protocol. I need to make it work with `https` using the `keytool` and certificates. On this server an API is running such that I dont need a domain name for it. So I want to make the ssl connection without a domain name using the ip address. I am running `apache tomcat 9.0.36` with the following `server.xml` configuration. And `ports : 12001, 12002, 8433, 433, 80, 8000, 8080` are open for testing purposes.

```
 <Connector port="12001" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
          connectionTimeout="20000"
          redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" maxThreads="1000" acceptCount="1000" minSpareThreads="50"/>  

    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool -->
    
     <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" /> 

     <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
          maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
          keystoreFile="D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.36\conf\keystore.jks"
          keystorePass="********"
          clientAuth="false" acceptCount="100"
          />
```

Ran the following command to generate the SSL certificate.

`keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -keystore keystore.jks -validity 365 -keysize 2048`

Checked the certificate (ok)
`keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks`

When I go to the https://ip:8433, I cannot connect to the server `this site cannot be reached` `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`
When I go to http://ip:12001, there is no redirect and `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Comment: Check the details of your question: your connector is running on port `443`, but you try to access port `433`. Besides that you use the wrong protocol: `http://<server_ip>:433` instead of `https://<server_ip>`. You also might have a firewall that blocks the connections.

Comment: it was a typo, also the port now is 8433

Comment: Check the firewall settings (or disable the firewall during the test) and in the case of the TLS connector, check Tomcat's logs for errors reading your keystore.